# pugi::next_sibling returned something strange

Tags: c++, pugixml

I have xml like this

```
<w:document>
<w:body>
    <w:p>
        <abra-cadabra>
            <w:t>test</w:t>
        </abra-cadabra>
    </w:p>
    <w:p>
    </w:p>
    <w:p>
        <w:t>test1</w:t>
    </w:p>
</w:body>
```

I use pugixml to parce it.

```
pugi::xml_node cur_sibling = cur_node.next_sibling();
    if (cur_sibling.name() == "")
        find_sibling(cur_node.parent());
```

here cur_node is test node, and next_subling structure looks like this:
[cur_sibling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KD8yn.png)
sorry for russian, it sais can not read memory
so I cant do anything with it, and attempt to get it's name cause stack owerflow error. Have no idea what going on, why it didn't return null node?

Answer (score 0):

Your test node does not have a *next_sibling*, `cur_sibling` is then an invalid xml_node that you can test with:

```
if (!cur_sibling)
```

If you look at the signature of the member function:

```
const char_t* xml_node::name() const
```

You can see it's not returning a string but a `const char_t*`. Then your comparison with operator `==` is comparing the (different) adresses.

Comment: Thanks! It seems to work well, but can you explain me this: as i understood the documentation, when node is last child next_subling returns null node, which's name is an empty string. Although, i used to use the same construction and it worked as i expected.
But not this time. What am i missing?

Comment: @Stupid_Hedgehog Indeed, it's [returning an empty string](https://github.com/zeux/pugixml/blob/master/src/pugixml.cpp#L5455) where I expected an assertion. The problem is your comparison. See edited answer.

Comment: @Stupid_Hedgehog You just can't compare `char *` with operator ==, you have to use [`strcmp`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcmp).